# How to lift CRT to the type level

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, modulo

Hi I have the following function

```
crt :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
```

which calculates the Chinese remainder theorem on the input. I would like to lift this to the type level as I have a datatype parameterised by a Nat which to invert I need to split the modulus up by the CRT. I have been trying to get to grips with the process but there are limited resources online explaining it and I don't quite understand them so if anyone here could help that'd be great :).

Edit :

As advised I'm including more details of my problem here - so the above was  a slight simplification of my exact problem; these are the 2 main datatypes I have :

```
data Polynomial (n :: Nat) = Poly {coef :: [Mod n]}
data PolynomialQuotient (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) = PolyQ {value:: (Polynomial n)}
```

The m in the definition of the PolynomialQuotient is the natural number which when converted to an Integer and then converted to a polynomial will become the quotient of the Polynomial Ring.
What I'm trying to do is to define recip for PolynomialQuotient however I have problems when n (the modulus of the coefficients) is a composite number as my division algorithm fails to terminate. What I want to do is to take a PolynomialQuotient and map it to the equivalent list of Polynomial Quotients given by CRT.

i.e given 3x^2 + 1 (mod p(x)) (mod 4) this would be mapped to [1x^2 +1 (mod p(x)) (mod 2), x^2 (mod p(x)) (mod 2)]. Then they can be inverted and the results put back together to form the inverse. However I can't just write this function and apply it as above as Haskell has no idea it get deduce KnownNat for the factors of a number.

Comment: I think you'll have a bigger change of an answer if you include your value level implementation here, then it's easier to see what the challenges could be.

Comment: I think you're going to have trouble moving the extended Euclidean algorithm to the type level, as it produces signed output. Also, that type doesn't look right. I'd expect the list to be the input, given the statement of the CRT.

Comment: There are existing libraries that work with signed natural numbers, such as `units` (see Data.Metrology.Z), which also defines division, which might help.